# Openstack CLI client gives an error: ImportError: No module named queue

Tags: openstack, python-2.x

Openstack uses python 2.7 and not 3.x. In some cases, pip install python-openstackclient, would install a broken openstack client. Hence openstack client would not work. It would give following error: ImportError: No module named queue

```
$ openstack --help
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/bin/openstack", line 10, in <module>
    from openstackclient.shell import main
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/openstackclient/shell.py", line 24, in <module>
.
.
.
    from openstack import utils
  File "/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/openstack/utils.py", line 13, in <module>
    import queue
ImportError: No module named queue
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, please replace "**import queue**" with "**from multiprocessing import Queue as queue**"

In my case, I had to replace it in following two files:

```
/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/openstack/utils.py
/Users/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/openstack/cloud/openstackcloud.py
```